# Add Swagger authorization using ef core with identity and JWT Token

Tags: .net, jwt, swagger, identity, blazor

I have a blazor app project that basically copied this authorization:

[BlazorWithIdentity](https://github.com/stavroskasidis/BlazorWithIdentity)

Now I need to add Swagger authorization and to be honest I don't know how to do that and I cannot find anything that would fit. Everybody implements it via OAuth2, JWT Token or some thing called BasicAuth, which I thought would work for me, but it didn't.

What I did for now is I implemented JWT Authorization and it works fine for Swagger authorization, but now Login endpoint doesn't authorize the user, though I can get the token from the response. Can I somehow connect those two authorizations? I need Login endpoint to authorize the user, Logout endpoint to deauthorize it etc.

Comment: I think you should clarify your terminology, starting with "Swagger authorization".

Comment: @HenkHolterman You can add that green Authorize button at the top of the Swagger and you can Authorize yourself via i.e. JWT Token or BasicAuth. If you get authorized, you can use authorized endpoints.

Comment: Please provide some code.